# How do I Dispose of an object not via using (property initializer)?

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen examples of objects which are automatically disposed through the 'using' statement, which is a definitive way of defining the scope of the object and forcing a dispose.

I've also seen dispose called in the finally of a try/catch/finally block.

However, say the disposable object is instantiated as a property initializer in a form class how do I ensure that Dispose is called in that scenario?

Comment: The form has a Dispose method. In there, you can call Dispose of your other objects, tying them to the lifespan of the form.

Comment: Assuming WinForms, you could call `Dispose()` on your object in `Form.Dispose()` override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Form to implement IDisposable and just call the Dispose() method on your object in your Form.Dispose()

Comment: Perfect then, even easier.

Comment: @openshac No, actually, not easier, because the `Dispose` method is implemented in the designer class, and if you modify it manually you run the risk of your code being removed if/when the designer class is re-written.

Comment: If form already implements IDiposable, do I just override the dispose method and clean-up any child objects?

Comment: Noi just add a call to myObject.Dispose() in the form's Dispose() method (which you will find in the designer file).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like this:

```
var form = new Form { Dependency = new DisposableDependency() };
```

then `Form` class should dispose it in own `Dispose()` method, the best way would be implement own `IDisposable` as well or dispose such disposable dependencies in `Close()` method if such exists.

Comment: `Form` already implements `IDisposable`, you just need to ensure that this other object gets disposed within the `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are [various techniques](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/10/howtodisposemembersfromforms.aspx) to accomplish this task depending on your needs.  From MSDN:

`When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed.`

If the lifespan of the property is directly tied to the form, then you can Dispose of the object in the overridden Dispose method in the designer file.  So when you call `form.Close()`, the Disposable object will be disposed of as well.

```
   /// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }

        myDisposableObject.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

This particular part of the designer file is safe from being over-written,  However, developers may overlook the designer file assuming auto-generated code.  Another means of disposal such as hooking into the dispose event of the Form may be more appropriate to your needs.

Comment: consider adding a partial method in the code behind, such as `AddtionalDispose` so that the partial method can be implemented in the non-designer .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

make you're class inherit from IDisposable
than use 
using(var myclass=new myclass())
{}
Hope this helps you.